# Составить словарь и списка кортежей

Tags: python

Есть список кортежей, (где идут id покупателя, количество товаров, сумма покупки)

```
orders = [
      (111, 3, 1200), (118, 9, 8000),
      (111, 10, 1000000), (119, 9, 13300),
      (156, 10, 11000), (123, 9, 11200),
      (178, 20, 3200), (178, 5, 8900),
      (156, 9, 8000), (123, 4, 3500),
      (101, 9, 8000), (101, 8, 1000),]
```

Надо из него получить словарь примерно такого вида:

```
discount_system {101: {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 9000},
            111: {'discount': 15, 'total_sum': 1001200},
            118: {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 8000},
            119: {'discount': 5, 'total_sum': 13300},
            123: {'discount': 5, 'total_sum': 14700},
            156: {'discount': 10, 'total_sum': 19000},
            178: {'discount': 5, 'total_sum': 12100}}
```

То есть надо если id совпадает, то складывать сумму (например id 111 встречается два раза и надо в итоговый словарь положить, сумму для id 111 10000+1200) и т.д.

Пока придумалось такое:

```
for i in orders:
    discount_system.update({i[0]:{'discount':0, 'total_sum':i[2]}})
print(discount_system)
```

И получаю словарь со словарями внутри, НО вот как применить условие, что если ID уже есть в словаре, то делай сумму не пойму...

Comment: Метод get() возвращает значение по указанному ключу. Если указанного ключа не существует, метод вернёт None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```py
orders = [
      (111, 3, 1200), (118, 9, 8000),
      (111, 10, 1000000), (119, 9, 13300),
      (156, 10, 11000), (123, 9, 11200),
      (178, 20, 3200), (178, 5, 8900),
      (156, 9, 8000), (123, 4, 3500),
      (101, 9, 8000), (101, 8, 1000),]

discount_system  = {}

for i in orders:
    id_, discount, total_sum = i
    if id_ in discount_system.keys():
        discount_system[id_]["total_sum"] += total_sum
    else:
        discount_system[id_] = {"discount":discount, "total_sum":total_sum}
```

Содержание `discount_system`

```
{111: {'discount': 3, 'total_sum': 1001200}, 
118: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 8000}, 
119: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 13300}, 
156: {'discount': 10, 'total_sum': 19000}, 
123: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 14700}, 
178: {'discount': 20, 'total_sum': 12100}, 
101: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 9000}}
```

Вопрос, что со значением `discount`? В данной логике оно не меняется

Comment: discount наверное тоже должно суммироваться.

Comment: @Александр это же количество процентов, думаю, что там не все так просто

Comment: А ну да да :-).

Answer (score 3):

[dict.setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
orders = [
    (111, 3, 1200), (118, 9, 8000),
    (111, 10, 1000000), (119, 9, 13300),
    (156, 10, 11000), (123, 9, 11200),
    (178, 20, 3200), (178, 5, 8900),
    (156, 9, 8000), (123, 4, 3500),
    (101, 9, 8000), (101, 8, 1000)
]

discount_system = {}
for id_, _, sum_ in orders:
    discount_system.setdefault(
        id_,
        {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 0}
    )['total_sum'] += sum_

for k, v in discount_system.items():
    print(k, v)
```

> ```
> $ python discount_system.py
> 111 {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 1001200}
> 118 {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 8000}
> 119 {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 13300}
> 156 {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 19000}
> 123 {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 14700}
> 178 {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 12100}
> 101 {'discount': 0, 'total_sum': 9000}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby

orders = [
      (111, 3, 1200), (118, 9, 8000),
      (111, 10, 1000000), (119, 9, 13300),
      (156, 10, 11000), (123, 9, 11200),
      (178, 20, 3200), (178, 5, 8900),
      (156, 9, 8000), (123, 4, 3500),
      (101, 9, 8000), (101, 8, 1000),]
```

создадим список кортежей, сгруппированных по первому значению.
(будет считать сумму элементов по сгруппированному значению кортежей любой длины)

```
tpl_of = [(i, ) + tuple(sum(k) for k in zip(*j))[1:]
                         for i, j in groupby(sorted(orders), lambda x: x[0])]
```

p.s. обязательно отсортирован, иначе будут повторения, здесь lambda - *"по какому значению будет происходить группировка"*.

и далее создаем словарь из этого списка кортежей

```
discount_system = {i[0]: {'discount': i[1], 'total_sum': i[2]} for i in tpl_of}
```

на выходе получаем с суммой по всем значениям (у вас указано, что *discount* - это количество покупок, поэтому я думаю, что это тоже важно):

```
 {101: {'discount': 17, 'total_sum': 9000}, 
111: {'discount': 13, 'total_sum': 1001200}, 
118: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 8000}, 
119: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 13300}, 
123: {'discount': 13, 'total_sum': 14700}, 
156: {'discount': 19, 'total_sum': 19000}, 
178: {'discount': 25, 'total_sum': 12100}}
```

Answer (score 2):

вариант с использованием библиотеки pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(orders, columns=['id','discount','total_sum'])
res = df.groupby('id').sum().to_dict('index')
'''
{101: {'discount': 17, 'total_sum': 9000},
 111: {'discount': 13, 'total_sum': 1001200},
 118: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 8000},
 119: {'discount': 9, 'total_sum': 13300},
 123: {'discount': 13, 'total_sum': 14700},
 156: {'discount': 19, 'total_sum': 19000},
 178: {'discount': 25, 'total_sum': 12100}}
```

Comment: элегантно, просто и эффективно )